# Create tag in a project that includes its submodule repository files

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules

I have a question related to git tag and submodules.

Assume I have a projectA, and it has a submodule may be called moduleA. 
Then I create a tag in projectA, but when I download this tag from our remote repository (Which is Gitlab), it doesn't contain files from moduleA, it only contains an empty folder of that module.

How could I include files from the submodule in the whole tag when I download it from Gitlab?

N.B: I used `git tag -a "v1.0.0" -m "version 1.0.0"` to generate tag from our project repo.